# Rename and transform filename via Bash

Tags: linux, bash, rename, mv

I am newbie, so pls dont swear me.
I need to rename and transform files from old to the new name via shell script (bash) in linux.
I have a files like that `now_360p_2014-05-19-13.21.14.266-FET_0.mp4`, but i need to get this `2014-05-19_13-21-14_now_360p_0.mp4`
How can I do this?

**small addition** - if the file is in use by another process, it can not be touch.
I' ve tried this to explore new result to change the command:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in (/opt/media/rec/*.mp4);
do
    nf=$(echo $f | sed -r 's/([^.]+\.)([^.]+\.)([0-9])_([^_]+)(.*)/\1\4_\2\3\5/')
    echo mv $f $nf
done
```

but i have an error ((

> auto.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   'uto.sh: line 3:`for f in (/opt/media/rec/*.mp4);

Comment: FET and milliseconds should be cut from new name

Comment: See @Peque's answer. You can add options to `find` so that only such files are considered, e.g. `-mmin -540`

Comment: have a folder name in output filename. e.g. "2014-05-15_16-42-13_/opt/media/rec/now_360p_0.mp4"

Comment: Getting rid of that is trivial (e.g., see the `basename` command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to handle those "column based" pattern, awk would be easier:

```
kent$  echo "now_360p_2014-05-19-13.21.14.266-FET_0.mp4"|awk -F_ -v OFS="_" '{print $3,$1,$2,$4}'
2014-05-19-13.21.14.266-FET_now_360p_0.mp4
```

### UPDATE

I didn't check your desired output carefully. there are some other thing you want to change, e.g. the `dot`, the `FET`, the `-` between date and time... now this should work for you (gawk):

```
awk -F_ -v OFS="_" '{sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",$3);
                    $3=gensub(/-([^-]*$)/,"_\\1","g",$3);
                    gsub(/\./,"-",$3);
                    print $3,$1,$2,$4}'
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "now_360p_2014-05-19-13.21.14.266-FET_0.mp4" |
        awk -F_ -v OFS="_" '{sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",$3);
                $3=gensub(/-([^-]*$)/,"_\\1","g",$3);
                gsub(/\./,"-",$3);
                print $3,$1,$2,$4}'
2014-05-19_13-21-14_now_360p_0.mp4
```

Comment: have a folder name in output filename. e.g. "2014-05-15_16-42-13_/opt/media/rec/now_360p_0.mp4". how to delete foldername ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
for f in (/opt/media/rec/*.mp4);
```

If you run a simpler example `for f in (/opt/media/rec/*.mp4); do echo $f; done`, you will get the same error.

Try using find:

```
for f in $(find /opt/media/rec/ -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.mp4");
```